# É possível passar por todas as linhas de um select, através de algum loop na procedure do MySQL?

Tags: mysql, loop, stored-procedures

Eu tenho uma aplicação que desenvolvi a alguns anos atrás na pressa, e só depois comecei a trabalhar para melhorar o desempenho dele.
Neste app, tem uma parte do processo que eu executo várias ações seguidas no banco, inicialmente meu plano era colocar numa procedure mas eu tive um problema, que era não conseguir tratar linha por linha de um select no MySQL (para exibição de relatório), e devido a falta de tempo pra estudar o resolvi tratando no backend diretamente com python.

Hoje tenho o mesmo cenário, preciso gerar um relatório a partir de dados de outra tabela mas preciso ler linha por linha e não queria fazer isso com python, porque aumentaria processos tem alguma forma de fazer isso numa procedure?

Eu poderia fazer um loop definindo o `limit` a cada volta para tratar as linhas, mas queria saber se é possível fazer com menos código, dentro de uma procedure, tipo:

```
while (select `acao`,`regiao`,`id`,`data` into @acao, @regiao, @id, @data 
       from `historico` where `contrato` = '142';) Do

       if (@acao == '1') then 
           insert into movimentacao_acesso (`idm`, `data`, `regiao`) values (@id, @data, @regiao); 
       end if;

end while;

select * from movimentacao_acesso;
```

Desde já agradeço. Só preciso rodar esse loop na procedure

Comment: Em resumo, você precisa pegar os dados de um select com um certo filtro (where) e inserir em outra tabela?

Comment: Isso, na verdade são inserções diferentes em duas tabelas diferentes, dependendo da acao da linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que pode ser feito, é efetuar o `insert` com base em um `select`, para isso, não é necessário nem mesmo criar um `procedure`.

---

Você criar a estrutura para o `insert`:

```
insert into movimentacao_acesso (idm, data, regiao)
```

Porém não passa o `values` e sim um `select`, onde a ordem dos campos no `select` precisa ser a mesma que você criou para o `insert`, logo ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
select id
       , data
       , regiao
    from historico
   where contrato = 142
     and acao = '1';
```

Juntando tudo, você teria a seguinte instrução SQL:

```
insert into movimentacao_acesso (idm, data, regiao)
  select id
       , data
       , regiao
    from historico
   where contrato = 142
     and acao = '1';
```

> Veja online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/603e706/1

Comment: Puxa que bacana, ficou pequeno! Uma dúvida. Neste exemplo, se o retorno do select for 120 linhas, ele fará 120 inserts?

Comment: Sim, ele faz o ```insert``` conforme o retorno do ```select```, por isso o ```WHERE``` é super importante! Você poderia encapsular essa ideia em uma ```procedure``` para que os dados do ```where``` passem a ser dinâmicos... caso seja necessário. Já fiz testes e a performance disso é incrível! :)

Comment: Obrigado, você retirou muitas linhas de código.